# Console Input for pyspark

Tags: pyspark, bigdata

Is there a input() function in Pyspark through which i can take console input.
If yes, can u please elaborate on it.

How do i write the following code in PySpark  :

```
directory_change = input("Do you want to change your working directory ? (Y/N)")
sc.input("Do you want to change your working directory ? (Y/N)")
a = directory_change.upper()
if a == "Y" or a == "YES" :
        directory = input("Enter your working directory")
        directory = directory.replace("\\","/")
        os.chdir(directory)
```

`

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work that way.

To achieve the same effect, you could try to provide arguments to the script using `application-arguments` when submitting the task. C.f. [the doc on spark-submit](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html)

Comment: can you elaborate on how it can be achieved ? doc on spark submit doesn't give any info about submitting inputs. it is all standard user definitions

Comment: You cannot "submit inputs", but you can provide arguments to your script via `--application-arguments` and find them in `sys.argv`

Comment: why not ? That can definitely be legit in some cases. And it is feasible in scala spark. in pure python too. But somehow in pyspark input() function misbehaves

Comment: Because spark applications/scripts are meant to be executed on worker instances which you don't have a tty open. You may be able to create a wrapper python script to take the input then start up the spark script -- but in that case you're just doing `input` from python.